# Trying to get large image to display when the thumbnail is hovered

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, hover

I'm trying to create a gallery of thumbnails, and once the thumbnail is hovered over, it will display the full size version in a separate box.

The problem right now is that I cannot get an image to display at all, when its corresponding thumbnail is hovered over.

This is the HTML:

```
<img class="thumb1" src="image.jpg">
```

And the actual, full-size image is in another section:

```
<img class="fullsize1" src="image.jpg>
```

This is the CSS, but it's not working:

```
img.fullsize1 { display:none; }
img.thumb1:hover + img.fullsize1 {display:block;}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide a code snippet

Comment: Without a code snippet I think both g16media zimalks' and Ricky's answer may be the way to go. Look at your markup and use the Web Inspector to see the changes on :hover.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your larger `<img>` directly follows your thumbnail in the markup.

The `+` represents the [**adjacent sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```css
img.fullsize1 {
  display: none;
}
img.thumb1:hover + img.fullsize1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class="thumb1" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img class="fullsize1" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```

---

> once the thumbnail is hovered over it will display the full size version in a seperate box.

To achieve this, it depends on how the markup is presented.

You can try the following:

```css
.box {
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.box img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fullsize {
  display: none;
}
.box--thumb:hover + .box--fullsize > .fullsize {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--thumb">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<div class="box box--fullsize">
  <img class="fullsize" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

---

With that markup you can achieve something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.gallery {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery__item--fullsize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.gallery__item--fullsize > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gallery__item--thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
}
.gallery__item--thumb:nth-child(3) {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.gallery__item--thumb:nth-child(5) {
  left: initial;
  right: 1em;
}
.gallery__item--thumb:hover + .gallery__item--fullsize {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--fullsize">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500?text=1">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--fullsize">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500?text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--fullsize">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500?text=3">
  </div>
</div>
```